# SQL Where clause filter by indexed columns first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, where-clause

I have a query where I want to filter by 2 columns - 1 of which has a non-clustered index, the other is a varchar (200) - non indexed.

```
ProductID (PK)  |  Category (IX)  |  Description  
--------------------------------------------
1                  cat1              random text describing the product
2                  cat2              diff txt for another product      
3                  cat1              another desc another product
4                  cat1              a great product
5                  cat2              not so great
```

My query will look like

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Category = 'cat2' AND Description like %...%
```

My question is - will SQL have the smarts to filter by the indexed column first - thereby reducting the number of queries that require the more resource intensive query over non-indexed fields included in the `where` clause?

Or does the order of columns in the where clause determins which are executed first?

Comment: The order of the columns in the `WHERE` doesn't matter. What does, however, is the cost of doing a seek on the non-clustered index followed by a key lookup on the clustered index vs doing a scan of the clustered index. Doing the former may be *more* costly and so would not be the "smart" option.

Comment: To add to what Larnu said, if the index is found to be not selective enough (many rows have `cat2`, based on histogram statistics) the engine will likely decide the index isn't helpful enough and fall back to a scan. If on the other hand it was highly selective (only a handful of rows have this value) an index lookup plus clustered index lookup becomes the clear winner.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to populate a #tmp table to force query by index, then apply the additional where criteria to the tmp table? Or am I better to let SQL manage everything?

Comment: You are almost always better off letting the optimizer do its thing, because it doesn't miss the mark that often when it comes to index use -- naive developers like you and me tend to overestimate how useful an index is, and forcing the engine to use it because it "has to" speed things up usually doesn't work. If you want to force the use of an index you can do so with the [`OPTION (INDEX ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table#index---index_value---n----index---index_value-) table hint.

Comment: If you do want to experiment with various strategies, always look at execution plans and also consider `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON` (and, on a test server, do `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` to clear the buffer pool and time how long a query takes when the table isn't resident in memory yet -- this scenario can differ quite a bit vs. the time needed for a table that's already there).

Comment: It doesn't matter if Description is indexed or not - you've used wildcards at front and rear so the query is non-sargable. Beyond that I'm with Jeroen Mostert - let the optimiser do it's thing.
Incidentally you could try using `AND CHARINDEX('searchitem',Description > 0` - it might be more performant that double-wildcarding